# Send an NSObject by watchConnectivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I am working on a WatchOS 2 version of our app and stuck on the fact that i can only send a string with the function "updateApplicationContext:(NSDictionary *)".

I hoped I could make an NSObject with some variables to send over as object in this NSDictionary. After a few days I still didn't find a solutions for this problem. Is there anyway to send a NSObject over the function?

If there is no way to send an NSObject is it possible to send something like a struct?

My code is a s follows:

```
-(void)updateWatchData
{
    //Objective-C
    if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
        WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
        session.delegate = self;
        [session activateSession];

        if(session.isPaired) {
            //Objective-C
            DLog("Sending watch data");
            NSMutableArray *kalenderData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            for (int i = 0; i < self.dataContainerViews.count; i++) {
                DataContainerView *container = self.dataContainerViews[i];

                if(container.listType == ListGPKalender){
                    for(int j = 0; j < container.tableArray.count; j++){
                        GrandPrix *gp = container.tableArray[j];
                        WatchGrandPrix *watchGp = [[WatchGrandPrix alloc] init];

                        watchGp.gpnaam = gp.gpnaam;

                        [kalenderData addObject:watchGp];
                    }
                }
            }

            NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"kalenderData", nil];
            NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kalenderData, nil];
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

            NSError *anyError;
            if([[WCSession defaultSession] updateApplicationContext:dictionary error:&anyError]){
                DLog("Data Send!");
            }else{
                DLog("Failed to send data with error: %@", anyError);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the NSObject is just:

```
@interface WatchGrandPrix : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *gpnaam;

@end
```

The error i got was

> Failed to send data with error: Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7010
>   "Payload contains unsupported type."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Payload contains unsupported type.,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Only pass valid types.}

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the object to a property list representation (basically instead of an array of your model object you have an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary is a mapping of values where the key is the name of the variable and the value is a plist compatible type representing the value).

Another option, which will be less bandwidth efficient, is to make your object NSSecureCoding compliant and use something like NSKeyedArchiver to convert it to NSData and send an array of NSData's.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I used an array of dictionaries to send the data over. The keys are the variable and de objects the values of course. It works perfectly and have a nice working watch app so far! Thanks your was great!

Answer (score 3):

I have been sending custom objects by serializing them to a Json string. I created a [github project](https://github.com/lehn0058/SwiftSerializable) that serializes any object quickly for this purpose. It includes a playground that shows how to do the serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Thanks, I like the approach. But I'm having problems when I have a UIColor inside my object. My dictionary looks like that: ["title": test, "content": lol, "color": UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1] and the WatchConnectivity framework says: Payload contains unsupported type. What can I do to work around this?

Comment: This is because UIColor isn't in Apple's supported types. You could convert your UIColor into three properties (red, green, and blue) during serialization and have a method on it that converts those properties to the UIColor for when you need it.